# Как бороться с вечной нехваткой памяти в PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

PHPStrom 2016 на машине (i5 / 16gb / 512ssd)- через пол часа работы с любым проектом начинаются тормоза, еще через пол часа вот такая штука:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и так каждый день!

Подскажите возможное лечение?

Comment: ну так поставь Xmx - 1,5 Гб и всё :)    А еще, возможно, в проекте какие-то файлы громадные лежат. Я как-то раз в файле php расположил вложенный массив размером в 1000 (распечатка выборки из БД) - так шторм завис, т.к. пытался в память загрузить такой объем :D  Так что увеличивай тут память и проверяй что за монстро файлы в проекте лежат и убирай их из проекта (делай им Exclude например)

Comment: Дело в том, что если я поставлю Xmx= 1,5 Гб, то у меня комп вообще повиснет мертво, потому что даже с 512 Mb тормозит не только шторм, а вместе с ним и винда начинает вся тормозить. И только потом уже в шторме вот это окно выскакивает.

Comment: эмм.... `i5 / 16gb / 512ssd` - тормозит намертво?  Значит тут проблема где-то еще и это очевидно. Например жуткая нехватка места  на системном диске. Или дохлый SSD

Comment: не знаю, пока шторм не включаю, никаких проблем с системой. Все начинается по истечении 15 мин. работы в шторме.

Comment: 512 Мб - это слишком мало для более-менее крупного проекта. При таком объеме памяти очень много процессорного времени уходит на ее очистку для новых объектов. Увеличение памяти до 1,5 Гб, как было предложено выше, не только ускорит работу PhpStorm за счет наличия необходимых данных в RAM, но и снизит нагрузку на CPU.